# Spacy Memory Usage Performance Improvements

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, spacy-3

I have tens of thousands of documents, where each doc is about ~150k characters, ~25k white-space bounded tokens, and ~2k unique tokens. I'm using Spacy to pre-process (stopword removal and lemmatization). The preprocessing depends on `token.pos_` and `token.lemma_` as shown below.

I learned that I incorrectly implemented Spacy by disabling the `tok2vec` pipeline component (needed for POS tagging); after fixing that, my memory usage is crazy high. The app hangs then the OOM killer kills my python.

My approach is to feed the docs into `nlp.pipe` in chunks of 100 and `n_process=4`. This worked fine until fixing the above bug. The only way the app runs without hanging/OOM killer is to reduce the number of docs I feed into the pipe ~25-50. Reducing `n_process` to 1 doesn't seem to have an impact. Here's my rough approach:

```
import spacy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import unidecode
import re

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
nlp.max_length = 5000000
nlp.disable_pipe("parser")
nlp.disable_pipe("ner")
nlp.enable_pipe("senter")

def pre_pre_process(record, synswap=True):
    (doc_id, text) = record

    # partial pre-preprocessing = just strip HTML
    text1 = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser").get_text(separator=" ")

    # full pre-preprocessing = do all the pre-preprocessing
    text2 = " ".join(text1.strip().split())
    text2 = unidecode.unidecode(text2)
    text2 = text2.lower()
    
    return (text2, {'doc_id': doc_id, 'strip_html': text1, 'ppp': 'full-ppp'})


def pre_process_text(doc, convert_num=True, lemmatization=True,
                     punctuations=True, remove_num=True, special_chars=True,
                     stop_words=True, short_char=True, remove_edgar_junk=True):
    fully_processed = []
    edgar_jnk_patt = re.compile('(?is)ex-\d+\.?\d*')  # noqa: W605
    edgar_jnk = []

    for token in doc:
        # (token, token.pos_, token.is_stop, token.is_punct, token.lemma_)
        flag = True  # assume every token should be added to the vocab
        edit = token.text
        # remove stop words
        if stop_words is True and token.is_stop and token.pos_ != 'NUM':
            flag = False
        # remove punctuations
        if punctuations is True and (token.pos_ == 'PUNCT' or token.is_punct) and flag is True:
            flag = False
        # remove special characters
        if special_chars is True and token.pos_ == 'SYM' and flag is True:
            flag = False
        # remove numbers
        if remove_num is True and (token.pos_ == 'NUM' or token.text.isnumeric()) and flag is True:
            flag = False
        # remove short tokens
        if short_char is True and len(token) < 3 and flag is True:
            flag = False
        # convert tokens to base form
        elif lemmatization is True and token.lemma_ != "-PRON-" and flag is True:
            edit = token.lemma_
        # remove edgar junk
        if remove_edgar_junk is True:
            if token.i < 10:
                if token.text.endswith(('.htm', '.html')):
                    flag = False
                    edgar_jnk.append(token.lemma)
                elif edgar_jnk_patt.search(token.lemma_):
                    flag = False
                    edgar_jnk.append(token.lemma)
            if token.lemma in edgar_jnk and flag is True:
                flag = False

        # append tokens edited and not removed to list
        if edit != "" and flag is True:
            fully_processed.append(edit)
    return fully_processed

# In the complete script, `data` is queried from a DB limited by a param, `query_limit = 50`. It continues in a while true loop grabbing `query_limit` records until there aren't any more records to query. 

# For reproducibility, `data` sample here: https://gist.github.com/roablep/09731a9a0996fc82aecedb6fcb7c026a

completed_jobs = []
pipeline_texts = [pre_pre_process(d) for d in data]
for doc, context in nlp.pipe(pipeline_texts, as_tuples=True, n_process=4):
    tokens = pre_process_text(doc)
    completed_jobs.append((context, tokens))
```

My questions are:

1. Why is `tok2vec` eating so much memory?
2. How can I profile what's happening in `nlp.pipe`?
3. Is there a better way to implement this pipeline overall?
4. Is there a better way to implement the pre-processing? (Is there a built-in Spacy approach or is what I have pretty standard)

Related to question 2: Interesting spikiness in memory:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spaCy is not really designed to work with 25k word documents (which is like a short novel) as single strings. You should split you documents into some natural sub-unit, like paragraphs, and process them. Note that even if you don't use spaCy, working with documents of that length without splitting them up somehow will be challenging.

Comment: Makes sense. And presumably I'd still use the pipeline capability, correct? Does splitting up a doc change how a dictionary is constructed?

Comment: Yes, after splitting your input into multiple chunks you could just use the pipeline as normal. I'm not sure what you mean by "dictionary"? But for the built-in components, especially those in the pretrained pipelines, context more than a paragraph or two won't affect the results significantly.